# Exception and messagebox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

i have a problem with exception handling. Im doing a windows form app to check the validity of social security number. However, when i test it the system takes over.
Instead of having the error shown in my MessageBox, it shows directly in the code (debugging mode).
Below is Validation, my error checking method and the button in which i call it.
Thanks for your help

```
private bool Validation(String s, out string message) 
{
    message = "";
    bool res = true;
    if (isNumeric(s) == false)
    {
        message = "Valeur non numérique";
        res = false;
    }
    else if (s.Length > 15)
    {
        message = "Vous avez entré trop de caractères";
        res = false;
    }

    if (s.Length < 15)
    {
        message = "Vous n'avez pas entré assez de caractères";
        res = false;
    }

    int genre = Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(0, 1));
    if (genre != 1 || genre != 2)
    {
        message = "Genre inconnu";
        res = false;
    }

    int mois = Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(3, 2));
    if (mois < 1 || mois > 12)
    {
        message = "Le mois entré est incorrect";
        res = false;
    }

    long r = Convert.ToInt64(s.Substring(0, 13));
    int clef = ((int)(97 - (r % 97)));
    int r1 = Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(13, 2));
    if (clef != r1)
    {
        message = "La clef est incorrecte";
        res = false;
    }
    else
    {
        res = true;
        TxtNumSS.Clear();
    }

    return res;
}

private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string message = string.Empty;
    if( Validation(TxtNumSS.Text,out message) == false)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error", message, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Clef valide! ");
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to learn about exceptions. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch

Comment: Good formatting is your friend Licuen, use it. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: You should also read up on `long.TryParse` and `int.TryParse`. Not sure about your country's format, but with a US (or Canadian) number a good algorithm is to take the input string, remove the separators (`input.Replace("-", string.Empty)`). Then use `int.TryParse` to test that it's a valid number (perhaps testing the range). Finally, use a custom format string to convert it back into a string of exactly the right format (leading zeros, separators, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if we should use any exceptions here, routine (and a bit tedious) checking is enough.

Let's redesign `Validation` method: we'll return either empty string (for no error) or corresponding error message:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static string ValidationMessage(string s) {
  if (null == s)
    return "null string";
  if (s.Length > 15)
    return "Vous avez entré trop de caractères";
  if (s.Length < 15)
    return "Vous n'avez pas entré assez de caractères";
  if (!s.All(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9')) // all characters in s are [0..9] digits
    return "Valeur non numérique";
  if (s[0] != '1' && s[0] != '2')
    return "Genre inconnu";

  int mois = int.Parse(s.Substring(3, 2));
  
  if (mois < 1 || mois > 12)
    return "Le mois entré est incorrect"; 

  long clef = 97 - long.Parse(s.Substring(0, 13)) % 97;
  long r2 = long.Parse(s.Substring(13, 2));

  if (r2 != clef)
    return "La clef est incorrecte";

  return "";
}
```

Then we can use it:

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  string errorMessage = ValidationMessage(TxtNumSS.Text);

  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage)) {
    //TODO: check: should we clear TxtNumSS here?
    TxtNumSS.Clear();
    MessageBox.Show("Clef valide! ");
  }
  else 
    MessageBox.Show("error", errorMessage, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);  
}
```

Comment: Thank you, made me see my mistakes.